# Is it possible to use Drupal to host an online asset?

Tags: 10

I have tried to host a CSS asset file on Github's raw content library to call it from a local Windows JavaScript file, like this:

```js
cssElement.setAttribute("href", "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/USER/REPOSITORY/main/DIRECTORY/FILE.css");
```

GitHub prevented access to such files to reduce bandwith from their servers.

I have a Drupal website, can I somehow host this CSS asset file on that website securely and then call it from the local JS file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breaking it down:

> can I somehow host this CSS asset file on that website

Yes. Conventionally, you might store it in a subfolder of a custom theme/module, but it's your codebase so you can essentially choose where it goes. You could put it in the public file system, for example (typically /sites/default/files), or in a folder you add to the docroot and track/deploy with git, it's really up to you.

> securely

Assuming you mean TLS, this is down to your server config. If your site is served over https, then any static assets can/will be too.

> then call it from the local JS file

Assuming your website has an accessible domain, then yes. A file uploaded to ./docroot/assets/foo.css, for example, would be available at https://bar.com/assets/foo.css. You may need to adjust [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) settings on the host website to allow this.

Answer (score 1):

On a site where Drupal is installed, static files are still served first. This means that, for example, in a site that answer to https://example.com, the *assets/FILE.css* file placed in the documentation root directory of Apache server can be accessed using https://example.com/assets/FILE.css.

This happens because the .htaccess file used by Drupal contains the following directives. (The comment explains what the directives do.)

```
# Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to
# index.php.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

If you use Nginx, you need a file that is equivalent to .htaccess, which is only used by Apache Server, and that file would contains analogous directives.

If then you need the *FILE.css* to be dynamic, you can create a module that responds to the *assets/FILE.css* route and return CSS content.